# How to add continuous geom_vline to multiple facets in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
data <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),y1=c(-2,-7,-12,-17,-22,-27,-32,-37,-42,-47),y2=c(1003,2003,3003,4003,5003,6003,7003,8003,9003,10003),y3=c(-3,-6,-9,-12,-15,-18,-21,-24,-27,-30))
```

I want to draw three scatter plots in ggplot2, with the same independent `variable(x)` and three different dependent `variables(y1,y2,y3)`. Then add continuous `geom_vline(geom_vline(xintercept=3.2))` to them like the following picture, but I don't know how to do it. Is there anyone can help me?

[image: Plot example]